# Mongoid embedded query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

Hi I have embedded documents but i can't query them by id. I can output all with inspect and there are the right ids but querying them is not possible.
I have a Course Model which embeds_many :course_members and a CourseMember Model with embedded_in :course, :inverse_of => :course_members

I tried this without any success:

```
puts Course.where("course_members.id" => params[:id])
```

With this code i can reach the rigth document:

```
c = Course.where("course_members.accepted" => 2).all
c.each do |l|
 l.course_members.each do |f|
  puts f.inspect
 end
end
```

But how can i get my data with one Mongoid query?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess

```
puts Course.where("course_members._id" => BSON::ObjectId(params[:id]))
```

The real id argument in MongoDB is `_id`, the function `.id` in mongoid is just a convenient wrapper.

**Edit:** You also have to convert your string `params[:id]` to a correct BSON ID.

Comment: Course.where("course_members._id" => BSON::ObjectId.from_string(params[:id]) )